# Unhide UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a split view app with a button in the detail view. I have set the button as hidden in the Inspector in Interface Builder. I want it to be visible though, when the user selects an file from the table. Where should i insert the following line to make this happen?

```
myButton.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: It's a split view app so the button is in the detail view and that method is in the root view controller. Does it still go there even though the button is declared in the detail view controller?

Comment: You will need to include the detail view controller's .h file in your root view controller's .m, so that you can reference that button, but yes, it does still go there.